# What does "kernel-resident" mean?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

Quoting from the `ifconfig` man page:

> `ifconfig`  is  used to configure the kernel-resident network
>   interfaces. It is used at boot time to set up interfaces as necessary.
>   After that, it  is usually only needed when debugging or when system
>   tuning is needed.

What does kernel-resident mean?

Answer (score 1):

The `kernel-resident network interfaces` are network interfaces linked with kernel modules.

This term is used to make the distinction with [Linux drivers in user space](https://lwn.net/Articles/703785/).